# @font-face not displaying locally or in browser

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I can't seem to get my @font-face to work at all, neither locally or when previewing in browser. my CSS is as follows:

```
@font-face { 
 font-family: chopin-script.regular;
 src: local('chopin-script.regular'),
 url('/fonts/chopin-script.regular.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

My folder structure:

**HTML:** Site folder > HTML files

**CSS:** Site folder > CSS folder > CSS files

**Fonts:** Site folder > Fonts folder > Font files

I have been through all the other similar questions, and as far as I know, I've done everything that's been said, and to no avail, apologies if there is something I haven't tried somewhere that I'm not seeing. I have tried this same code with an .otf version of the font too.

regards.

**Edit:**

I used FontSquirrel to generate the font, and installed it as so:

```
@font-face { 
font-family: 'ChopinScript'; 
src: url('/fonts/ChopinScript.eot'); 
src: url('/fonts/ChopinScript.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('/fonts/ChopinScript.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/ChopinScript.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/ChopinScript.svg#webfont') format('svg'); 
}
```

It now displays correctly locally, but when previewing it in Firefox and IE it still doesn't show. However, it does work in Chrome. They're the only browsers I have installed.

Comment: If this is a font you bought, I suggest you to import it in [FontSquirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) first. The syntax you used doesn't seem right to me.. Especially the 'font-family' declaration. Normally the name of the font-family is enclosed in single quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post this as an answer but I can't comment. Are you allowed dots in the name of fonts without needing quotes? I usually put quotes around it if it has spaces or dots to ensure the name is alright with CSS. Try it as `font-family: 'chopin-script.regular';` and see if there's any difference.